# Windows 7 computer not waking for home server backup

Tags: windows-7, windows-home-server

I have just installed Windows 7 and now my computer won't wake from hibernate for nightly backups from Windows Home Server. As soon as I turn it on the morning it will backup then.
It was running with no problems on Vista and I haven't changed any other settings in the bios and things.
I found on the network adapter in bios that there was an option to allow this device to wake the computer, I have checked that but it still won't wake.
Is there anything that I can do? I have seen other questions similar to this on here but non had a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will be patched in WHS powerpack 3, out in 14th December, according to the release notes. You may be able to get the Beta still, which solves the problem - see [here:](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/windowshomeserver/archive/2009/09/28/windows-home-server-power-pack-3-update.aspx)

> Windows 7 client PCs will not automatically wake up to do a backup:  Windows 7 users can work around this by doing manual backups, or also by turning on the wakeup timer in the Windows client Control Panel.  Power Pack 3 beta also fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

[No Sleep](http://www.catfood.net/blog/2008/12/prevent-sleep-during-scheduled-tasks.asp) "is a command line tool that disables sleep or hibernate, runs a batch file or program and then enables sleep or hibernate again. It will run on any recent version of Windows."

Haven't tried it myself- yet. But I'll use it to enable my morning alarm.

Answer (score 0):

See this article:
[Wake up your computer from standby or hibernation, perform an action, and send it back. Automatically.](http://dottech.org/freewaresr/4431)

It describes a freeware named WakeUpFromStandby, available for Vista (which might still work on Windows 7):

> Can restore almost every Windows-based
>   operating system from a Stand-by mode
>   (and some from hibernation) that
>   support ACPI (Advanced Configuration
>   and Power Interface) (For support
>   check computer's BIOS as well as
>   Control Panel -> Power Options);